# Can a library I use in my Android app .apk collide with that library used in another app?

Tags: android, installation, apk

I linked jets3t into a test app and got logcats I've not yet seen during install ..

```
02-08 12:21:11.825: DEBUG/PackageParser(1086): Scanning package: /data/app/vmdl28891.tmp
02-08 12:21:12.059: DEBUG/PackageManager(1086): Scanning package org.jets3t
02-08 12:21:12.075: INFO/PackageManager(1086): /data/app/org.jets3t-1.apk changed; unpacking
02-08 12:21:12.082: DEBUG/installd(1009): DexInv: --- BEGIN '/data/app/org.jets3t-1.apk' ---
02-08 12:21:12.481: DEBUG/dalvikvm(26867): creating instr width table
02-08 12:21:12.715: DEBUG/dalvikvm(26867): DexOpt: 'Lorg/apache/commons/codec/Decoder;' has an earlier definition; blocking out
02-08 12:21:12.715: DEBUG/dalvikvm(26867): DexOpt: 'Lorg/apache/commons/codec/BinaryDecoder;' has an earlier definition; blocking out
02-08 12:21:12.715: DEBUG/dalvikvm(26867): DexOpt: 'Lorg/apache/commons/codec/Encoder;' has an earlier definition; blocking out
02-08 12:21:12.715: DEBUG/dalvikvm(26867): DexOpt: 'Lorg/apache/commons/codec/BinaryEncoder;' has an earlier definition; blocking out
... many more ...
'Lorg/apache/commons/logging/impl/WeakHashtable$Entry;': multiple definitions
02-08 12:21:12.973: DEBUG/dalvikvm(26867): DexOpt: not verifying 'Lorg/apache/commons/logging/impl/WeakHashtable$Referenced;': multiple definitions
02-08 12:21:12.973: DEBUG/dalvikvm(26867): DexOpt: not verifying 'Lorg/apache/commons/logging/impl/WeakHashtable$WeakKey;': multiple definitions
02-08 12:21:12.973: DEBUG/dalvikvm(26867): DexOpt: not verifying 'Lorg/apache/commons/logging/impl/WeakHashtable;': multiple definitions
02-08 12:21:13.168: INFO/dalvikvm(26867): DexOpt: not resolving ambiguous class 'Lorg/apache/commons/logging/LogFactory;'
... many more ...
02-08 12:21:13.364: INFO/dalvikvm(26867): DexOpt: not resolving ambiguous class 'Lorg/apache/commons/logging/LogFactory;'
02-08 12:21:13.387: DEBUG/libgps(1086): GpsInterface_inject_location( 37.378289, -122.059655, 897.000 )
02-08 12:21:13.387: DEBUG/dalvikvm(26867): DexOpt: load 111ms, verify 540ms, opt 21ms
02-08 12:21:13.543: DEBUG/installd(1009): DexInv: --- END '/data/app/org.jets3t-1.apk' (success) ---
02-08 12:21:13.551: INFO/ActivityManager(1086): Force stopping package org.jets3t uid=10084
02-08 12:21:13.559: DEBUG/PackageManager(1086):   Activities: org.jets3t.MainActivity
02-08 12:21:13.832: INFO/installd(1009): move /data/dalvik-cache/data@app@org.jets3t-1.apk@classes.dex -> /data/dalvik-cache/data@app@org.jets3t-1.apk@classes.dex
02-08 12:21:13.832: DEBUG/PackageManager(1086): New package installed in /data/app/org.jets3t-1.apk
```

I'm reading that as shared library overwrites.  If it is, I'm wondering if this is a result of something I did wrong?  If I overwrite, what are the chances that other apps could break?  Of course any properly created library will be backward compatible .. and I guess Android package mgr would not replace a package with an older variant?

Plus "multiple definitions"?  "not resolving ambiguous class"?

Oh yeah.. the test app seems to work fine so far :)

Thanks.  Guess I need to go read up on pkg install, load, and link lol.

Comment: Anyone recommend where to read up on pkg install, load, and link?  JetS3t asks me to include commons-codec, commons-httpclient, commons-logging, and log4j jars that it provides.  Stubs?  Why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe the only way you'd actually damage another application on a properly secured device is if you replace an .apk it depends on.

It looks to me more like you are installing an .apk which contains classes that duplicate some in the platform libraries of that device.  The new duplicates are being ignored.  This is not uncommon, as there is a variety of highly attractive 'private' functionality in the platform which doesn't have "headers" (sorry, wrong term, but conveys the idea) in the sdk.  This makes it hard to write against without including stubs to satisfy the compiler (or using reflection to find the real classes at runtime).  At install time those stubs get ignored with warning messages as you are seeing.

This is not necessarily good practice, but it tends to work as long as the private functionality on the device continues to work as expected - ie, it can break in an an OS upgrade or when the program is installed on a different device.  The Android people are pretty persistent in telling you not to use private functionality for that reason.

Error/warning message remaining in shipping code that works despite them is also not great practice, and is unfortunately something really endemic to the android stack itself.

Comment: Thanks Chris! but I clearly need to learn more about the space.  The jets3t package includes jars for well knowns such as log4j which I expect is already available and visible nearly everywhere.  Why would a package include and specify the use of such jars?

Comment: it might need internal/additional parts of them which are not exposed in the sdk

Comment: Anyone interested in further on this might find http://www.netmite.com/android/mydroid/dalvik/docs/dexopt.html useful... ack, given that the code works I spose I can't spend more time on this now.